# How to cook meat?

Tags: meat, hamburgers, learning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the secret of making a really juicy burger?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13570/what-is-the-secret-of-making-a-really-juicy-burger)

Well I want to be more independent and cook for my self. How can I say, cook a burger on a frying pan? I know you have to do it right to be safe to eat. I only actually know how to fry bacon, and make scrambled eggs...

Comment: Thanks, I tried making a pretty thin beef burger. I somewhat burned it, the outside was crispy, I did that because I was worried of it cooking to fast on the outside but not the inside, when I did eat it though the inside definitely wasn't pink. IS that all there is to it really? is steak the same? I usually have steak rare.

Answer (score 1):

Fry or grill / broil the burger on both sides. Note how long you cook it for. When you think it might be done, slice it open down the middle (into two thin patties) and see if the middle is still pink; if it is, it's not done yet! In time you will learn how long a particular variety of burger takes.